# Dynamic Linq and generic objects - Public member 'Select' on type T not found

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, dynamic, dynamic-linq

I'm trying to create a generic method that accepts a collection object, a string representation of the object's type, and a dictionary(of String,String) whose keys contain properties of interest.

I want to then generate a dynamic linq query based on these inputs. It seems though that even after converting the input collection object to a strongly-typed object, dynamic linq won't work - it says `Public member 'Select' on type '{T}' not found` (where `{T}` is the strong type).

Here's basically what I've got:

```
Sub Testing123(ByVal data As Object, ByVal fieldDefs As Dictionary(Of String, String), ByVal myObjectType as String, ByVal myCollectionType As String, ByVal myAssembly As String)

    ' Type of object in the collection
    Dim properties = Type.GetType(myObjectType).GetProperties().Where(Function(p) fieldDefs.ContainsKey(p.Name)).ToList()
    ' Get type of the collection object (data)
    Dim thisType = Type.GetType(String.Format("{0},{1}",myCollectionType,myAssembly))
    ' Create strongly-typed collection object
    Dim data2 = Convert.ChangeType(data, thisType)
    ' Resolve select list from input
    Dim selectVars As String = "new (" & String.Join(", ", fieldDefs.Keys.ToList()) & ")"
    ' materialise dynamic query
    Dim result = data2.Select(selectVars) ' ERROR IS HERE

    For Each r In result
        Debug.Print(r.Title & " " & r.ViewType)
    Next
End Sub
```

It works OK if I pass a strongly-typed collection object in (e.g. rather than `ByVal data As Object`, `ByVal data as MyStrongType`) and do the equivalent dynamic linq query. But it seems that making the input `Object`, even though the conversion is successful (have confirmed in debug session), I get this error.

Note that the collection types are custom objects (SharePoint CSOM objects, in case that's helpful), not just `List(Of T)`.

Comment: Downvoter: grateful any constructive feedback...

Comment: The `Select` method can only be called on a reference of a type that is, inherits or implements the `IEnumerable(Of T)`. If your reference is not know to be such a type at compile time then it's not allowed. If you know that it will be that type at run time then you can cast as that type and then call `Select`, although you would also need to know what `T` is or else declare your method generic.

Comment: Thanks @jmcilhinney, appreciate your help. I've validated that everything works when the objects are strongly typed. My code *is* casting to a type that supports `Select` (see `Dim data2 = Convert.ChangeType(...)`). Have I missed something?

Comment: `Convert.ChangeType` is not a cast.  It returns an `Object` reference.  So you're trying to call `Select` on an `Object`, which is not allowed. A cast and a conversion are two different things. A cast changes the type of the reference used to access an object while a conversion changes the type of the object.  `Convert.ChangeType` does the latter while you need the former.

Comment: Ah thanks for that. I'll need to find out if I can dynamically cast - previous attempts wouldn't let me do it in an equivalent way to how I'm passing the `Type` argument in the `Convert.ChangeType` above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thinking about it further, the DLINQ version of `Select` must actually require an `IEnumerable` or an `IQueryable` rather than an `IEnumerable(Of T)`. I've had a quick look and can't find confirmation of that but I think it must be the case or it wouldn't be dynamic.  In that case, you can simply cast as that type, which wouldn't require any other changes to your code.

If an `IEnumerable` is all that's required then use this:

```
Dim result = DirectCast(data2, IEnumerable).Select(selectVars)
```

If an `IQueryable` is required then, as your object probably doesn't implement that already, you'd need this:

```
Dim result = DirectCast(data2, IEnumerable).AsQueryable().Select(selectVars)
```

This answer is a bit of an educated guess but it seems logical, so hopefully it's accurate.

Comment: Nice one, thanks - that's worked for what I'm doing. Cheers!